# How to start from beginning of the script after an exit?

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have lots of xml files and I want to extract some information from them, but some file doesn’t contain any information. So when I run my script on an empty file then I stop my script. But I don’t know to take next file in my directory if the current file is empty. 
Below a small part of my script.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import pandas as pd
import glob
import sys
import os

path = 'C:\Users\sky\Documents'
# Read all xml files of directory
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()



# Extract all books 
books = [ ]
for book in root.findall('.//Book/Message//'):
    name = book.find('Name').text
    if name is not None:
        books.append(name) 

df_final = pd.DataFrame(books, columns=['Book'])

if df_final.Book.count() == 0:
    sys.exit('No Book was found!')
    # how to take next file in my directory ?
authors= []
for auth in root.findall('./Book/Message/author'):
    if auth.attrib != {}:
        author = number.get('name')
        authors.append(author)

# I have  many loops like these two
df_final['Author'] = pd.DataFrame(authors)      


if os.path.isfile('books.csv') is False: 
    df_final.to_csv('books.csv', sep=',', mode='w', header=True, index=False) 

else: 
    df_final.to_csv('books.csv', sep=',', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
    print '\n', ' File Processed Successfully!', '\n'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you stop your script on an empty file?

Comment: You either want to create `books.csv` for each `.xml` file in your path or you want to do it using the last one. Either way your logic seems odd.

Comment: @zipa 
Not for each `.xml`, I append each result to my `books.csv`

Comment: @quamrana, Because it gives me error for other code blocks of my script.

Comment: Please update your question with the full text of the error so we can tell which line of code is causing it.

Comment: Then something is off with your indentation, you read `.xml` files and for each you overwrite the `tree` and `root` variable.

Comment: You seem to be nesting a dataframe within a column of a dataframe. Please show example XML so we can help with process here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the sentence "try". If you have a loop which opens the xml files, with this order it tries open the file and if it does not exit, pass and it does not raise the error.

```
for ...
    try:
       (action)
    except:
        pass #(or another action)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the loop going when there is an error, you can do this

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
    except:
        continue
```

In addition to this, I suspect that the following code should be placed inside the above `for` loop.

```
books = [ ]
for book in root.findall('.//Book/Message//'):
    name = book.find('Name').text
    if name is not None:
        books.append(name)
```

Otherwise, the `root.findall('.//Book/Message//')` will only apply on the last .xml file.

So, I suspect that your code should be like this

```
books = [ ]
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()        
        for book in root.findall('.//Book/Message//'):
            name = book.find('Name').text
            if name is not None:
                books.append(name) 
    except:
        continue
df_final = pd.DataFrame(books, columns=['Book'])

if df_final.Book.count() == 0:
    sys.exit('No Book was found!')
    # how to take next file in my directory ?
authors= []
for auth in root.findall('./Book/Message/author'):
    if auth.attrib != {}:
        author = number.get('name')
        authors.append(author)

# I have  many loops like these two
df_final['Author'] = pd.DataFrame(authors)      


if os.path.isfile('books.csv') is False: 
    df_final.to_csv('books.csv', sep=',', mode='w', header=True, index=False) 

else: 
    df_final.to_csv('books.csv', sep=',', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
    print '\n', ' File Processed Successfully!', '\n'
```